# Elasticsearch Nest multifield mapping not working

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, nest

http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/indices/put-mapping.html says I can do multifield mapping like this:

```
var result = this._client.Map<ElasticsearchProject>(m => m
    .Properties(props => props
    .String(s => s
    .Name(p => p.Name)
    .Path(MultiFieldMappingPath.Full)
    .Index(FieldIndexOption.not_analyzed)
    .Fields(pprops => pprops
        .String(ps => ps.Name(p => p.Name.Suffix("searchable")).Index(FieldIndexOption.analyzed))
    )
    ))
);
```

When I try, however, autocomplete doesn't work. I get this error:

[image: screenshot]

I installed the latest stable version of NEST (1.7.1) from NuGet but that doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to set up a [**`multi_field`**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html) mapping with NEST

```
void Main()
{
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"))
        .SetDefaultIndex("location-details");   
    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    var indexResult = client.CreateIndex(indexDescriptor => indexDescriptor
        .Index("location-details-v1")
        .AddMapping<LocationDetails>(mapping => mapping
            // map properties using the default conventions and
            // any NEST attributes
            .MapFromAttributes()
            // override default mappings explicitly
            .Properties(properties => properties
                .MultiField(multi => multi
                    .Name(p => p.Name)
                    .Fields(fields => fields
                        .String(s => s
                            .Name(p => p.Name)
                            .Index(FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)
                        )
                        .String(s => s
                            .Name(p => p.Name.Suffix("searchable"))
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    if (!indexResult.IsValid)
    {
        throw indexResult.ConnectionStatus.OriginalException;
    }
}

public class LocationDetails
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The `Name` property is mapped as a `multi_field` in Elasticsearch - The *default* mapping for the field is `not_analyzed` and will be the field used if referring to the field with no suffix. The other mapping `name.searchable` will be analyzed using the **[standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html)** by default.

The mapping in Elasticsearch looks like the following

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/location-details-v1/locationdetails/_mapping"

{
   "location-details-v1": {
      "mappings": {
         "locationdetails": {
            "properties": {
               "name": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed",
                  "fields": {
                     "searchable": {
                        "type": "string"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```